# Paging and TOP vs TAKE vs MAXITEMS in DocumentDb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Trying to implement paging and I'm not sure I understand the difference between TOP, TAKE and MAXITEMS.

I know they are set in different places, but they seem to be doing the same thing.

TOP vs TAKE looks like SQL vs LINQ as best I can tell.  But what, how does this differ from MaxItems?

TIA

Bill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By MaxItems do you mean MaxItemCount?

If so, it is set in the FeedOptions, it it controls the size of the batch of results that is returned by a document query. See the below example taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions.maxitemcount.aspx#P:Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.FeedOptions.MaxItemCount:

```
// Fetch query results 10 at a time.
var queryable = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Book>(collectionLink, new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 10 });
while (queryable.HasResults)
{
    FeedResponse<Book> response = await queryable.ExecuteNext<Book>();
}
```

In the above example, you are iterating over the results of the query 10 results at a time.

To further explain the difference, it will make sense to define a query with TOP 50, but with MaxItemCount 10. This means you are getting the top 50 results in your database, but getting the results 10 items at a time.

Comment: Yes, MaxItemsCount.  Sorry.  I was doing this from (my lousy) memory.  So TOP and TAKE basically do the same thing, which is to limit the entire result set from the database.  MaxItemsCount just controls the feed batch size.  Thanks, that helped a lot.